# Calculating the month difference between 2 colums in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to exclude some accounts that doesn't have an history of 5 months from my select statement

[image]

In the picture I have to exclude 'A' in the first 5 rows if the date difference in the first row and the 5th row is less then 5 months. Similarly for Alli, L, O, R etc

Comment: So you have to exclude all of them in the pic? (Just trying to understand the question.)

Comment: Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Could you provide the "expected result" please.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`:

For `MSSQL`:

```
SELECT Ori FROM TableName
GROUP BY Ori
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), Date, 112)) >= 5
```

Or

```
SELECT Ori FROM TableName
GROUP BY Ori
HAVING DATEDIFF(mm, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)) >= 5
```

For `ORACLE`:

```
SELECT Ori FROM TableName
GROUP BY Ori
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(Date, 'yyyymm')) >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use datediff(month, , )

Sample code:

```
select max (date) as maxdate, min(date) as mindate, Ori into #temp from table group by Ori

delete from table where Ori in (select Ori from #temp where datediff (month, mindate, maxdate) < 5)
drop table #temp
```